# Ruby on Rails ternary operator to display BOTH nil and false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, ternary-operator, scoping

I have 3 roles for User, call it standard, premium, and admin. Each can post posts. Premium and admin can choose whether to make private post or non private post (private: false or private: true). Standard user will not be given the option to choose whether their Post will be private/ not; by default, all of standard user's posts will have Private: nil status.

To summarize:

- Standard user's posts will always be private: nil
- Premium/ Admin user's posts can either be private: true or private: false

I am trying to make a scope so that when a standard user views index page, they see posts with Private: nil and Private: false, while Premium and Admin user can view all. My problem is, I can't come up with a ternary operators that allows standard users to view both private: nil and private: false Posts.

This is what I have on Post model:

```
  scope :visible_to, -> (user) { user.admin? || user.premium? ? all : where(private: false) || where(private: nil)}
```

The code above only displays Posts with private: false.
I've tried various combination:

```
... where(private: false || nil)}
```

Displays only private: false posts

```
... where(private: nil || false)}
```

Displays only private: nil posts

```
... where(private: nil && false)}
```

Displays only private: nil posts

```
... where(private: false && nil)}
```

Displays only private: false posts

and several other combinations -

I also noticed that when I switched the order of false and nil, it displays different results. I thought || or && operators are **non-commutative**. Maybe there is something about scoping or ternary operators that I was not aware...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using an authorization library like [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your just wondering how to do an or operator in a where? 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Section 2.3.3 Subset Conditions

```
... where(private: [false, nil])}
```

This should convert it into the sql

```
WHERE private in (false, nil)
```

Which is shorthand for multiple or statements in sql.
You can also use arel tables for more advanced sql features without breaking down to pure sql strings. Checkout out this article about your case using IN along with arel examples

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries

```
# It even handles arrays containing nil!
where(foo: ['bar', 'baz', nil]) # => (WHERE foo IN ('bar', 'baz') OR foo IS NULL)
```

Comment: It worked like magic!! (or maybe it was magic itself...) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To me the scopes are more meant to convey a slice of your data model.  The logic of this should either be in a model or controller depending on your setup and preferences.  Here is a general recommendation.

For the nil value, i would set a default for that column and migrate all of your current nil values to false.  It will make your life easier to have a definitive value for these instead of inferring that nil means false or undecided.

```
class User 
  def can_view_private_posts
    admin? || premium?
  end
end

class Posts
  scope :private, -> { where(private: false) }
end
```

Then let your service object or controller handle the relationship between the users being able to see private posts.

Comment: Never thought of doing it this way. Thanks!